# how to push values into arrays

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the form value in 'form' with the from i even have to sent the id which is stored in localhost.How can i do that .........anyone pls suggest help....

```
 onSubmit(form){

   console.log(form);
    var  str = localStorage.getItem('social');
    var loc = JSON.parse(str);
    var profile_id = loc.profile_id;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.post('http://localhost/angular/index.php/profile/addaddress', JSON.stringify(form),{headers:headers})
         .subscribe(
        response => {
          if(response.json().error_code ==0){
            alert('added successfully');
           }
           else{
            alert('fail');

            }
          })
     }


     }
```

Comment: What do you want to do? its not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onSubmit(form){
       ...
       var profile_id = loc.profile_id;
       form.profile_id=prifile_id;
       ...
}
```

Comment: I dont have profile_id in my form data and i want to send form along with profile_id which i got from local storage

Comment: Yes lately go it. So this code does it what you want.

Comment: Thank you micronyks

Comment: If you dont mine,can you please suggest some best resource for learning angular2

Comment: I learn it through [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/) but as it is in developing stage, you will come across many bugs or `not working examples`, at that moment google it and look for any specific article written for it. or you can always come to SO.